# Scons. Go recursive with Glob

Tags: scons

I using scons for a few days and confused a bit. Why there is no built-in tools for building sources recursively starting from given root? Let me explain:
I have such source disposition:

```
src
    Core
       folder1
       folder2
           subfolder2_1
    Std
       folder1
```

..and so on. This tree could be rather deeper.

Now I build this with such construction:

```
sources = Glob('./builds/Std/*/*.cpp')
sources = sources + Glob('./builds/Std/*.cpp')
sources = sources + Glob('./builds/Std/*/*/*.cpp')
sources = sources + Glob('./builds/Std/*/*/*/*.cpp')
```

and this looks not so perfect as at can be. Of cause, I can write some python code, but 
is there more suitable ways of doing this?

Comment: use [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) maybe?

Comment: @elmo, yes I find some snippets to solve the problem. But there is still the question why this is not the out-of-box feature? I mean if I doing something wrong?

Comment: Probably not wrong, but hierarchical builds tend to be more popular for some reason

Comment: I gonna to use hierarchical builds one level upper to build main project from subprojects. But in this case I have just a tree of sources in java-like manner.

Comment: Make a recursive builder that does what you'd like?

Comment: Presumably, your sub-directories would build something your current directory build depends on. Have a hierarchy of SConscripts, each of which builds from *.cpp and Return the result to form the dependency above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.
You need to write python wrappers to walking through dirs. You can find many recipes on stackoverflow. 
Here is my simple function which returns list of subdirs in present dir (and ignore hide dirs starting with '.' - dot)

```
def getSubdirs(abs_path_dir) :  
    lst = [ name for name in os.listdir(abs_path_dir) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(abs_path_dir, name)) and name[0] != '.' ]
    lst.sort()
    return lst
```

For example, i've dir modules what containts foo, bar, ice.

```
corePath = 'abs/path/to/modules'
modules = getSubdirs(corePath)
# modules = [bar, foo, ice]
for module in modules :
  sources += Glob(os.path.join(corePath, module, '*.cpp'))
```

You can improve getSubdirs function adding recurse and walking deeper to subdirs.

Answer (score 11):

As Torsten already said, there is no "internal" recursive Glob() in SCons. You need to write something yourself. My solution is:

```
import fnmatch
import os

matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('src'):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.c'):
    matches.append(Glob(os.path.join(root, filename)[len(root)+1:]))
```

I want to stress that you need Glob() here (not glob.glob() from python) especially when you use VariantDir(). Also when you use VariantDir() don't forget to convert absolute paths to relative (in the example I achieve this using [len(root)+1:]).

Comment: This almost did it for me, although I had to change my append argument to `Glob(os.path.join(root, filename))`. Your code was giving me blank arrays. Thanks though.

Comment: You don't need to use Glob once you have walked the tree. :)

Answer (score 3):

The Glob() SCons function doesnt have the ability to go recursive.

It would be much more efficient if you change your Python code to use the list.extend() function, like this:

```
sources = Glob('./builds/Std/*/*.cpp')
sources.extend(Glob('./builds/Std/*.cpp'))
sources.extend(Glob('./builds/Std/*/*/*.cpp'))
sources.extend(Glob('./builds/Std/*/*/*/*.cpp'))
```

Instead of trying to go recursive like you are, its quite common to have a SConscript script in each subdirectory and in the root SConstruct call each of them with the SConscript() function. This is called a [SCons hierarchical build](http://www.scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/c3186.html).

Comment: Should I use SConscript for every "package" of source? They are all built in same way without any per-package difference.

Comment: @AlexPovar, This approach is useful for allowing different compilation flags, defines, include paths, etc per directory. Additionally, you can "ship" separate directories with their individual build scripts. It may be excessive to have a SConscript per source directory, but you should have more than one global SConstruct.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of recursive `Glob`:

```py
from SCons.Environment import Base as BaseEnvironment

def __RGlob(self, root_path, pattern, ondisk=True, source=False, strings=False, exclude=None):
    result_nodes = []
    paths = [root_path]
    while paths:
        path = paths.pop()
        all_nodes = self.Glob(f'{path}/*', ondisk=ondisk, source=source, exclude=exclude)
        paths.extend(entry for entry in all_nodes if entry.isdir() or (entry.srcnode() and entry.srcnode().isdir())) # `srcnode()` must be used because `isdir()` doesn't work for entries in variant dirs which haven't been copied yet.
        result_nodes.extend(self.Glob(f'{path}/{pattern}', ondisk=ondisk, source=source, strings=strings, exclude=exclude))
    return sorted(result_nodes)
BaseEnvironment.RGlob = __RGlob
```

It tries imitate the standard `Glob` as closely as possible. The biggest difference is that beside the pattern is takes a root path as another argument. The pattern is then applied to this root path and every sub-directory in it.

This code adds function `RGlob` it to the base environment, which means you will be able to call it on every environment that is created after that. The best place to paste this is probably the file `site_scons/site_init.py`.

Comment: How do you call this? It seems like it requires 3 parameters, but Glob only takes 1 parameter.

Comment: @AaronFranke `self` is pythonic for `this`. You usually don't pass it explicitly; it is provided by the interpreter. You're left with 2 mandatory arguments. The first is `root_path`, the second is `pattern`. "It tries imitate the standard `Glob` as closely as possible. The biggest difference is that beside the pattern is takes a root path as another argument."

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
srcdir = './'
sources = [s for s in glob2.glob(srcdir + '**/*.cpp') if "/." not in s]
```

Comment: While this is a simpler solution, not using SCons' Glob() will miss handling variant dirs, and also miss any files not yet built which SCons knows about.

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution:

```py
env = Environment()
build_dir = 'build'
src_dir = 'src'
env.VariantDir(build_dir, src_dir, duplicate=0)
env = SConscript("SConstruct")

sources = Glob("build/*.cpp")
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src_dir):
    root = root[len(src_dir)+1:]
    for dir in dirnames:
        p = os.path.join(build_dir, root, dir, '*.cpp')
        sources.extend(Glob(p))
```