# How to specify wildcard artifacts subdirectories in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-8

I'm using GitLab CI to build a C# solution and try to pass some build artifacts from one build stage to another.

The problem is, that the artifacts are not located in a single directory but in different subdirectories, which however all have the same names `bin/` or `obj/`.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like the following:

```
...
stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    CALL %MSBuild% ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /**/bin/
      - /**/obj/
    expire_in: 6 hrs

test:
  stage: test
  dependencies:
    - build
  ...
```

I tried to capture the artifacts using different ways, e.g.

```
**/bin/
**/obj/
```

(invalid syntax), or

```
.*/bin/
.*/obj/
```

but that one did not find any artifacts, just as `/**/bin/` and `/**/obj/`, giving me following errors:

```
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: /**/bin/: no matching files
WARNING: /**/obj/: no matching files
```

**How can I specify a subdirectory pattern to be scanned for artifacts? Or is this even possible at all?**

Simply using

```
artifacts:
  untracked: true
```

is not an option, because of a huge untracked `packages/` subdirectory, which causes artifacts upload to fail because of a too large archive:

```
Uploading artifacts...
untracked: found 4513 files                        
ERROR: Uploading artifacts to coordinator... too large archive  id=36 responseStatus=413 Request Entity Too Large token=...
FATAL: Too large
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The [gitlab-ci-multi-runner](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner) build runner is built using [Go](https://golang.org/) and currently uses [filepath.Glob()](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob) to scan for any specified artifacts in [file_archiver.go](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/commands/helpers/file_archiver.go#L104).

Go doesn't seem to support the double star glob expression as discussed in another question [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner) at SO. So **there seem to be no way to use a full-featured `**/bin` expression at the moment**.

Because however all my projects are located at the same level below the solution root, it is still possible to use something like

```
artifacts:
  paths:
    - "*/bin"
    - "*/obj"
```

Note that the quotes (`"`) seem to be required, as well as **no** trailing path separator at the end.

It should also be possible to explicitly add more levels by adding more globbing expressions (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10598026/993388)):

```
paths:
  ...
  - "*/obj"
  - "*/*/bin"
  - "*/*/obj"
  ...
```

GitLab is tracking this issue [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2620), and will possibly be fixed in a future version.

**UPD:** due to mentioned [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2620) is closed and due to [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactspaths), since GitLab runner 13.0 it supports [doublestar.Glob](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bmatcuk/doublestar@v1.2.2#Match).

So it is now possible to write something like this:

```
paths:
  - "**/bin"
  - "**/obj"
```

And it will include all nested directories with names `bin` and `obj` in artifacts

Comment: I had no luck with the double quotes around the path. It worked without them. Also the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts) mentions only examples without quotes.

Comment: I have found that the double quotes are necessary.

Comment: Odd that quotes matter. But as far as I know, quoting is part of YAML syntax, so I doubt that the runner sees it with the quotes. I wonder why for one person it needed quotes and for another it needed no quotes.

Comment: No trailing slash!  Took me way too long to figure this out on my own.  I also found that I only needed quotes when starting the path with characters like * or % (Windows batch file variable expansion).

Comment: With gitlab-runner 11.11.0 on win64, globbing artifacts with ** works fine. (e.g.   artifacts:
    paths:
      - BuildArtifacts\Cli\\**)

Comment: You need to use quotes because `*` is a special character in YAML, an [alias](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#alias). Here is a [list of all the special characters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#strings) you must quote. "Although you can use double quotes, for these characters it is more convenient to use single quotes, which avoids having to escape any backslash ``\``". Not sure why trailing `/` doesn't work with globs. Seems like gitlab doesn't allow it and has nothing to do with YAML.

Comment: @dosentmatter tyvm - that was an annoying headache.

Comment: Looks like https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2620 just got implemented?